# Vertical centering of multirowcell text when specifying other column widths

Tags: tables, makecell

I have tables where I am trying to use two features together:

1. multirowcell (from the makecell package) for cells that span multiple rows with new lines inserted into the text in specific locations, and
2. specifying a fixed width for one or more other columns where I want the text to wrap (and to better control the overall table width).

When using these features together, I would like the text in the multirowcells to be vertically centered.

When using default table column types, makecell will vertically center the multirowcell text automatically. Table 1 in the MWE illustrates this behavior.

If a column type that allows for specifying the width of a column is used, even for a column in the table that does not use multirowcell, Table 2 in the MWE shows that makecell won't successfully vertically center the text in the multirowcells. In this example I've used a custom column type, but the same problem occurs when using, e.g., `p{}`.

Is there a way to help makecell vertically center the text when another column in the table has a specified width that causes the text in that column to wrap?

I tried using `\Gape[][]{}`, but even a large negative value for the depth correction will not vertically center the text. Inserting a `\vspace{}` above the text in the affected cells does work, but it requires guess-and-check approximation of the correct adjustment length for each affected cell. A solution that doesn't require specifying absolute length corrections would be ideal since I have several tables with different configurations that are affected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

Table 1

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Column A & Column B & Column C \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{4}{Some Somewhat\\Lengthy Text\\in a multirowcell} & Table Text & lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multirowcell{2}{A multirowcell\\More text} & adipiscing elit sed do elusmod tempur \\
    \cline{3-3}
    & & incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & Something & Whatever \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

Table 2

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|C{1.2in}|}
    \hline
    Column A & Column B & Column C \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{4}{Some Somewhat\\Lengthy Text\\in a multirowcell} & Table Text & lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multirowcell{2}{A multirowcell\\More text} & adipiscing elit sed do elusmod tempur \\
    \cline{3-3}
    & & incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & Something & Whatever \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration of tables without and with fixed column widths illustrating that multirowcell will not vertically center text in those cells with fixed column widths for some columns.]

Answer (score 2):

`\multirow` is designed for one-line cells, so you have to count the total number of *lines*, not of *rows*. In addition, adding vertical padding of cells may change the equivalent number of lines. Also, you can adjust the number of equivalent rows using a decimal number.

Here is a code for this case:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|C{1.2in}|}
    \hline
    Column A & Column B & Column C \\
    \hline
    \multirowcell{7}{Some Somewhat\\Lengthy Text\\in a multirowcell} & Table Text & lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multirowcell{2}{A multirowcell\\More text} & adipiscing elit sed do elusmod tempur \\
    \cline{3-3}
    & & incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \\
    \cline{2-3}
    & Something & Whatever \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: How does one calculate the correct number of rows to use? Based on the multirow documentation, it seems like the correct count is 9 for the multirowcell in Column A (counting rows in Column C), but on testing, 9 shifts that text too low in the cell. Is there a way to calculate the length programmatically with, e.g., the `calc` package?

Comment: Programmatically, I don't know. When I have to use multirow,  I always start from the number of lines, and adjust this value if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=1mm}


\begin{NiceTabular}{ccC{1.2in}}[hvlines]
    Column A & Column B & Column C \\
    \Block{4-1}{Some Somewhat\\Lengthy Text\\ in a multirowcell} & Table Text & lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur \\
    & \Block{2-1}{A multirowcell\\More text} & adipiscing elit sed do elusmod tempur \\
    & & incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua \\
    & Something & Whatever \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

- In `{NiceTabular}`, you have a command `\Block` for merged cells. You specifiy the number of *rows* and the number of columns.
- The key `hvlines` draws all the rules excepted in the blocks.

[image: Output of the previous code]